# How vtable and vptr is working when virtual method is called from non-virtual method

Tags: c++, vtable

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "Base class print function \n";
    }
    void invoke()
    {
        cout << "Base class invoke function \n";
        this -> print(); // case: 1
        print();         // case: 2
        Base::print();   // case: 3
    }
};
 
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "Derived class print function \n" ;
    }
    void invoke()
    {
        cout << "Derived class invoke function \n";
        this -> print(); 
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    Base *b = new Derived;
    b -> invoke();
    return 0;
}
```

For the above code I have hard time understanding how vptr and vtable of Derived and Base class is working for comments 1, 2 and 3. Why in case 1 and case 2 derived `print` is called ? A little arrow diagram will be very appreciated.

Comment: Inside `Base::invoke()`, case 1 and 2 are identical. In any case, a call to a virtual method using a pointer or reference to an object (even `this`) will go through the object's vtable at runtime to call the most-derived method. Qualifying the method call with a class type (like `Base::`) is a static call at compile-time, it doesn't go through the vtable at all. Note that in your example, `invoke()` is not virtual, so `b->invoke();` in `main()` will not call `Derived::invoke()`, only `Base::invoke()`

Comment: Where did you learn to use those first two lines of code? The include is not standard c++ and the second is not recommend

Comment: Unrelated: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` [loads the gun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301) and `using namespace std;` [takes the safety off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4581301). It is now very easy to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: i often fail to see what advantage it brings to discuss virtual dispatch in terms of the virtual pointer and virtual table. Those are implementation details that help to understand how it is implemented. How it works is always the same: You call `print`, its a virtual function, hence the function to be called is determined by the dynamic type of the object. `Base::print` does not use virtual dispatch because you fully qualify the function to be called. Thats really all.

Comment: offtopic: Your way of writing `this -> print();` is rather uncommon and hinders readability. Write `this->print();` or simply `print();`. On the other hand, style is opinion based and matter of opinions, what matters most is that at least you are consistent (though be prepared to change it once you work on code together with others)

Comment: Would you ask the same question for `b->print();` vs `b->Base::print();` when called in `main` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai calling member functions on `this` is a defensive style that prevents unintended call to global/namespace functions with similar name as member functions. It is actually good practice in library and generic programming. Getting used to it, makes refactoring code to a generic  library safer.

Comment: @Red.Wave my main point was about `this -> print()` vs `this->print()` and then I wrote more than I should have ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai don't bother with extra spacing; we're not doing python. Spacing is a matter of style. As long as the indentation is good enough to read, go easy on them.

Comment: Space is the final frontier. Since nothing was declared final, why is space an issue at all?

Answer (score 1):

`this -> print();` is just `print()` and uses the vtable to call the member of the actual type, as the function is virtual. That's what virtual functions are used for.

`Base::print();` just calls the indicated function, whether it is virtual or not. Often used by derived classes to first call the base class function and then do it own thing.